# Programmatically create flex div

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm looking for a way to insert a `flex` `div` into a document programmatically in Dart. Nothing crazy; just replicate:

```
<div flex></div>
```

It seems it should be easy, but I've read a lot of documentation and I couldn't find anything on the topic. I know I can simulate the behaviour using CSS `display`: `flex` and `flex-grow`, but I can't believe there's no way to do this programmatically. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```dart
document.body.append(new DivElement()..setAttribute('flex', ""));
```

I haven't tried it but I would expect the result to look a bit different like

```dart
<div flex=""></div>
```

but this should have exactly the same effect.

Comment: You could try to pass `null` as value instead of the empty String `""` to get the `flex` attribute without the `=""`.